# How to set the first ricv in the SCP02 unwrap function after extern-auth

Tags: java, smartcard, javacard, globalplatform

When I try to calculate the R-MAC of the response APDU after extended-authentication (`e-a`) successfully by SCP02, I always get "verify R-MAC failed".

I don't know how to initialize the first `r-icv` command. As the logs show, I set rMac to:

```
80E610002010A00000000053594E4A4F4E4553535344000A53594E4A4F4E45530000000000
```

and r-ICV is full zero, but verify response

```
006DFCFE5065740D309000
```

failed.

The key of the ISD is `40~4F`. I try to set rmac by icv after `e-a`, but also verified failed:

```
req:00A4040000
resp:6F108408A000000151000000A5049F6501FF9000
req:80502000084261A2F44EEC57EB00
resp:0000728314662294396620020046A58399EA65DDB9E2781A25689C719000
req:8482130010FAE81DD218F60A30A0F03ED2002B63B2
resp:9000
req:80E610002010A00000000053594E4A4F4E4553535344000A53594E4A4F4E45530000000000
resp:006DFCFE5065740D309000
```

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: It's about the GP specification.

Comment: Well, you can at least provide the script? I'm not going to go through your hex codes to find the mistake, and seeing that the code hasn't received an answer, I guess nobody really will.